# How to retry update after OptimisticLockException in the same TX

Tags: optimistic-locking

In my program I need to be able to retry row update after the row was updated by an external transaction. Hibernate/JPA throws `OptimisticLockException`, which I catch.
Upon retry I try to re-read the row from DB through JPQL/HQL but the select statement generates the same `OptimisticLockException`.
Is there any way to re-read the latest version of the row and update it in **THE SAME** transaction?

Answer (score 0):

`Session.refresh(object)` or `Session.lock()` would probably be appropriate.

Comment: Tried that but looks like the problem is in the isolation level. I'm trying to set it to READ_COMMITTED but for some reason it does not help. Still fighting with it.